# sql query to sum of amount

Tags: sql, query-optimization, firebird

I need a sum of amount for catid from the list (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16) if (catid>0 and catid<10) exists in receipt.

```
catid   amount      receiptno
1       2,00        1
12      3,00        1
13      4,00        1
1       2,00        2
1       2,00        3
13      4,00        3
12      3,00        4
13      4,00        4
```

The result should be

```
catid   sum
12      3,00
13      8,00
```

I have tried something, but SQL like this is too slow

```sql
select catid, sum(amount)
from mytable
where receiptno in (select distinct(receiptno) from mytable where catid>0 and catid<10) 
and catid in (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)
group by catid
```

Comment: Is `... 15, 15)` a typo, or as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `inner join` instead of subquery :

```
select catid, sum(amount)
from mytable t
inner join (
  select distinct(receiptno) 
  from mytable 
  where catid>0 and catid<10
) as s on s.receiptno = t.receiptno
and catid in (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15)
group by catid
```

Adding this Index could help :

```
CREATE INDEX mytable_catid_idx ON mytable (catid);
```

Comment: this solution is fine in my case, thx

Answer (score 0):

Better you can try the same query after removing 'distinct' from the sub query.

```
select catid, sum(amount)
from mytable
where receiptno in (select receiptno from mytable where catid>0 and catid<10) 
and catid in (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15)
group by catid
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the condition `receiptno in (select receiptno from mytable where catid>0 and catid<10)` with a correlated `EXISTS`:

```sql
select catid, sum(amount)
from mytable m
where catid in (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)
and exists (
  select 1
  from mytable
  where receiptno = m.receiptno
  and catid > 0 and catid < 10
)
group by catid
```

Additionally, Firebird doesn't always optimize `IN` well, so you may want to consider using `catid between 11 and 16` instead of `catid in (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like below:

```
;with cte as (
  select distinct receiptno 
  from mytable 
  where catid>0 and catid<10
) 
select catid,sum(amount)amount
from mytable A
join cte b on b.receiptno=a.receiptno
where  a.catid in (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15)
group by catid
```